# Joint Density Function Example

Tags: probability

f(x,y)= $\frac 1y$  for 0 < x < y <1

f(x,y)= 0 elsewhere

find P(x+y>.5):

$\iint$ $\frac 1y$ dxdy

I basically can't figure out the limits, since x and y are not only dependent on each other but also the probability statement itself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The region given is $ 0 < x< y<1$. In particular, this gives $0<x<y$

so we have $\int\int f(x,y) dx dy = \int_0^1\int_0^y \frac{1}{y} dx dy + \int_0^1\int_y^1 0 dx dy$

We can evaluate this, and we get

$\int_0^1\int_0^y \frac{1}{y} dx dy + \int_0^1\int_y^1 0 dx dy = \int^1_0 \frac{1}{y} *(y-0)dy + 0 = \int_0^1 1 dy = 1$

(edit) So to answer the probability statement for $P(x+y>0.5)$

$x+y>\frac{1}{2} \Leftrightarrow x > \frac{1}{2}-y$, so we are interested in the intersection of the regions $0<x<y<1$ and $1/2-y < x<1$. Combined, these give the region $\frac{1}{2} -y < x< y$ and $1/2 < y<1$

$$\int_0^1 \int_{1/2-y}^1 f(x,y) dx dy = \int_.5^1\int_{1/2-y}^y \frac{1}{y}dxdy$$

$$= \int_.5^1 \frac{1}{y}(2y-1/2) = \int_.5^1 2-\frac{1}{2y}$$
$$= 2*.5 -\frac{1}{2}(\ln(1) - \ln(.5))$$
$$= 1 - \ln(\sqrt{2})$$

Comment: Your solution only verifies the joint distribution statement. I need to find the probability that x+y>.5

Comment: So I did. My bad.

Comment: the only issue I have is with the integration of 1/y...I believe this integration will produce a natural log answer. Everything else is perfect!

Comment: Do you mean to distinguish between ln and log?

Comment: yea ln as natural log

Comment: log means natural log by convention in upper mathematics, but I'll change them for you.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle{%
{\rm f}\left(x,y\right)
=
{\Theta\left(x)\Theta\left(y - x\right)\Theta(1 - y\right) \over y}}$

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#ff0000}{\large\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm d}x
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm d}y\,{\rm f}\left(x,y\right)}
> =
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm d}y\,{\Theta\left(1 - y\right) \over y}
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm d}x\,
> \Theta\left(x\right)\Theta\left(y - x\right)
> \\[3mm]&=
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm d}y\,{\Theta\left(1 - y\right) \over y}
> \Theta\left(y\right)\int_{0}^{y}{\rm d}x\,
> =
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm d}y\,\Theta\left(1 - y\right)\Theta\left(y\right)
> =
> \int_{0}^{1}{\rm d}y = 
> \color{#ff0000}{\large 1}
> \end{align}

> \begin{align}
> \color{#ff0000}{\large{\rm P}\left(x + y > 5\right)}
> &=
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm d}x
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm d}y\,{\rm f}\left(x,y\right)
> \Theta\left(x + y - 5\right)
> \\[3mm]&=
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm d}y\,{\Theta\left(1 - y\right) \over y}\,
> \Theta\left(y\right)
> \int_{0}^{y}{\rm d}x\,\Theta\left(x + y -5\right)
> \\[3mm]&=
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm d}y\,{\Theta\left(1 - y\right) \over y}\,
> \Theta\left(y\right)
> \overbrace{\int_{y - 5}^{2y - 5}{\rm d}x\,\Theta\left(x\right)}
> ^{\left(~=\ 0\ \mbox{since}\ y - 5\ <\ 2y - 5\ <\ 0\
>          \mbox{when}\ 0\ <\ y\ <\ 1~\right)}
> =
> \color{#ff0000}{\large 0}
> \end{align}
>
> This result is quite obvious since ${\rm P}\left(x > 1\right) = 0$
> and ${\rm P}\left(y > 1\right) = 0$ such that ${\rm P}\left(x + y > 2\right) = 0$.

In general
$$
\left\langle\phi\right\rangle
\equiv
\int_{0}^{1}{{\rm d} y \over y}\int_{0}^{y}{\rm d}x\,\phi\left(x,y\right)
$$
[image]